# Getting users ip in php

Tags: php, ip

I made this code to get users ip on my site currently i am checking it in my localhost but it is returning something like ::1.
I am using xampp package , my code is

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

I would have got my ip 127.0.0.1 as i am on a localhost but it is returning ::1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4573033/2624391) on SO

> Localhost always translates to the loopback IP address 127.0.0.1 in IPv4, or ::1 in IPv6

So getting `::1` is actually expected behavior.

If you want to convert `::1` to the IPv4 equivalent of `127.0.0.1`, you can use PHP's `inet_ntop()` function. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699454/2624391) for more information.

```
$packed = chr(127) . chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(1);
$expanded = inet_ntop($packed);

/* Outputs: 127.0.0.1 */
echo $expanded;

$packed = str_repeat(chr(0), 15) . chr(1);
$expanded = inet_ntop($packed);

/* Outputs: ::1 */
echo $expanded;
```

Answer (score 0):

The IP address "::1" is the new Internet addressing system. If you are writing code to handle IP addresses it will come across these more and more.

Comment: ::1  is an exact IP address but is the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I don't think you can. IPv4 has about 4.3 Billion addresses whereas IPv6 has about 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456

Comment: If you are getting  ::1  it seems like your network has been set-up to use IPv6. If you are running Linux or FreeBSD you can force it to use IPv4 along side IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dig with shell_exec

```
$ip = trim(shell_exec("dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"));
echo ("My public IP: ".$ip);
```